# Сервер возвращает 403

Tags: javascript, mysql, post, get

Локально сайт работал хорошо, но когда поставил залил его, но появились ошибки: открывается страница логина и я могу залогиниться или создать нового пользователя, у меня стоит проверка login check, если пользователь не залогинился то дальше не пустит, но у меня логин проходит а логин чек нет, что делать?

`GET https://shopfishsite.onrender.com/users/login-check 403 (Forbidden)`

P.S. Настройки аксиоса

```js
const instanse = axios.create({
  url: 'https://shopfishclient.onrender.com',
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
  baseURL: 'https://shopfishsite.onrender.com',
})
```

И настройки корса

```js
app.enableCors({
credentials: true,
methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
origin: [
  'https://shopfishclient.onrender.com',
],
  });
```

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: Тогда оставлю прост текстом